# Regex for phone number with specific area code and format

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to create a regular expression that would validate a specific phone number with an 868 area code and particular format
h
thus I want these

```
8680000000

(868) 000 0000

868-000-0000

868 000-0000
```

to pass validation but these

```
8880000000

767-000-0000

868-0000000

(868)0000000
```

to fail validation.

So far I got:

```
^((\(){0,1}(868){1}(\)){0,1})+:?((((\ |\-)(\d{3})(\ |\-)):?\d{4})+|(\d{4,7}))
```

But

```
(868)0000000
```

is validating

Comment: Is there a broader rule as to what you want to pass and fail, that connects these examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is somewhat hard-coded because you are having some specific requirements like validating `868-000-0000` but not `868-0000000`.

Regex is:

```
(^\(868\)\ \d{3}\ \d{4})|(^868\d{7})|(^868\-\d{3}\-\d{4})|(^868\ \d{3}\-\d{4})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uD6iH4/1)

Comment: i think this would be the answer...should have thought about it like that....seeing that i needed a specific format

Answer (score 3):

I genuinely do not understand why everyone need to validate a phone number with strict spacing, bracketing, hyphenation, and god-knows-what-else requirements.

Strip out all unnecessary characters, validate what needs validating, move on with life.

```
$phone = '(868) 555-1234'; // or 868 555.1234 or +868x55-5-123-4 etc
$phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone); // 8685551234
if( substring($phone, 0, 3) == '868' ) {
  // great success
}
```

Bonus round. Format your data for hu-man display:

```
$phone_display = sprintf('(%s) %s-%s',
  substring($phone,0,3),
  substring($phone,3,3),
  substring($phone,6,4));
```

Comment: You need to negate the character class.

Comment: While I agree, it sounds like OP wants certain valid phone number formats to fail, so this solution wouldn't meet their needs

Comment: Wouldn't that report `$8,685,551,234` as a valid phone number? It's always trivial to write code that matches the text you want but mach harder to not match the text you don't want.

Comment: @EdMorton anything you put in the 'phone number box' should be assumed to be a phone number. It is no one's fault but the user's if they're inputting incorrect values.

Comment: I admit this isn't really my area but isn't the whole point to be able to tell the user when they input an invalid value, e.g. they enter their social security number or zip code or some monetary amount (like I showed in my previous comment) or anything else in the phone number box instead of in whatever the correct box on the form is? If we just take whatever digits were entered and discard everything else I think we'd be missing an opportunity for our form to be a bit more robust and user friendly.

Comment: @EdMorton sure, but different people write things differently. Phone numbers in particular. Even the monetary value you've specified is rife with commas. It is best to strip out all superfluous characters [sanitization] and then check the data against its most basic form. [validation] If you want to write regular expressions for every possible way someone could write a phone number or dollar value I'm not going to stop you, but I'm also not going to stop pointing out that it's a waste of time.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to validate every possible phone number format and I HATE when I enter a credit card number like `...123-4567` on a site and it barfs because it required `...1234567` but I disagree that stripping a possible phone number down to just digits is the right approach as it's useful to tell the user if the "phone number" they entered contains a `%` or `$` or `A` or anything else that is NEVER part of a phone number or enter 3 digits when a minimum of 10 (or whatever) is required. We can agree to disagree...

Comment: You answer would have been accept but I do need that specific syntax for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Such regex

```
^(\(?868\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s|-)\d{4}|868\d{7})$
```

Validate these

```
8680000000
(868) 000 0000
868-000-0000
868 000-0000
```

Not validate

```
8880000000
767-000-0000
868-0000000
(868)0000000
```

`match[1]` contains number

[**DEMO**](https://www.regex101.com/r/mM1mI6/1) and explanation of the regex

Comment: I know he didn't put it as a failure, but it matches these as well `868-000 0000`, `868000 0000`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some conditionals

```
 # ^(\()?868(?(1)\)[ ]\d{3}[ ]\d{4}|(?:(?:(-)|([ ])|)\d{3}(?(2)\2|(?(3)[ -]))\d{4}))$

 ^                             # BOS
 ( \( )?                       # (1), Form (xxx) xxx xxxx
 868                           # 868 Area Code
 (?(1)                         # Need Form 1 ?
      \)
      [ ] \d{3} [ ] \d{4} 
   |                              # else
      (?:
           (?:
                ( - )                         # (2), Form xxx-xxx-xxxx
             |  ( [ ] )                       # (3), Form xxx xxx[ -]xxxx
             |                              # Form xxxxxxxxxx
           )
           \d{3}      
           (?(2)                         # Need form 2 ?
                \2 
             |                              # else
                (?(3) [ -] )                  # Need form 3 ?
           )
           \d{4}      
      )
 )
 $                             # EOS
```

Passed:

8680000000
(868) 000 0000
868-000-0000
868 000-0000

Failed:

8880000000
767-000-0000
868-0000000
(868)0000000

Answer (score 0):

You could write one regular expression that matches all the formats, but there is no rule that says you have to.

Matching each format separately makes your code quite a bit more readable:

```
function matchPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) {
    $regex = [
        '/^(?P<prefix>868)(?P<first>\d{3})(?P<second>\d{4})$/',
        '/^(?P<prefix>868)-(?P<first>\d{3})-(?P<second>\d{4})$/',
        '/^(?P<prefix>868)\s(?P<first>\d{3})-(?P<second>\d{4})$/',
        '/^\((?P<prefix>868)\)\s(?P<first>\d{3})\s(?P<second>\d{4})$/',
    ];
    foreach ($regex as $reg) {
        if (preg_match($reg, $phoneNumber, $match) === 1) {
            return $match;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP uses EREs like `awk` or `grep -E` does:

```
$ grep -E '^((868([0-9]{3}|[- ][0-9]{3}-))|(\(868\) [0-9]{3} ))[0-9]{4}$' file
8680000000
(868) 000 0000
868-000-0000
868 000-0000
```

or if you like `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
^((868(\d{3}|[- ]\d{3}-))|(\(868\) \d{3} ))\d{4}$
```

Anything briefer would match other phone number formats that you didn't specify as being valid and so I'm assuming are invalid.